# How can I create a referral link in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel and want a referral link like this one:

```
domain.com/register?ref=username&pos=Left or right
```

I have tried:

```
{{url('/')'./register?ref=Auth::user()->name}}
```

I have also tried:

```
{{ route('register',ref=Auth::user()->id)}}
```

But both lines are not working and giving me errors. So, how can I create a referral link?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And take the tour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your routes are defined, so a quick and dirty solution would be this

```
{{ url('/register?ref=' . Auth::user()->name) }}
```

Comment: there are named routes

Comment: if i need ?pos=$ab  after username then what i will do ?

Comment: If you have named routes, you can just do `{{ route('register', ['ref' => Auth::user()->name, 'pos' => $ab]) }}`